# Synchronous operation On Node.js (Large data Computation)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6, array-algorithms

**EDIT**

Changes made against the comments

I have Four `Arrays`.

`commonOrdersList --length around 40k
storeA  --length close to 100k
storeB  --length around 110k
storeC  --length close to 100k`

of objects of different size looks something like

```
[
 {
  "orderId": "someUniqId",
  "orderTime": 1477764124822 //timestamp
 }
]
```

There is no particular ordering of items in array.

What I have to do is find if there is any order that is present in `commonOrderlist` is also present in any of three stores i.e `storeA`, `storeB`, `storeC` and filter out most recent orders by comparing order **time**.

It is like getting union while comparing three four arrays of different size.

I tried Iterating over each object/order present in `commonOrderList` and then passing each item over to other stores but this lead to **memory stack size exceeded Range error**

I did something like

```
      function getRecentOrders () {
        commonOrderList.forEach(val => {
            storeA.forEach(item => {
              if (val.orderId === item.orderId && item.orderTime > val.orderTime) {
                    let orderDetails = {
                          "orderId": item.orderId,
                          "orderTime": item.orderTime
                    }
                    recentOrders.push(orderDetails);
                    uniqOrderIdSet.add(orderId);
            })
            storeB.forEach(item => {
              if (val.orderId === item.orderId && item.orderTime > val.orderTime) {
                   let orderDetails = {
                          "orderId": item.orderId,
                          "orderTime": item.orderTime
                    }
                    recentOrders.push(orderDetails);
                    uniqOrderIdSet.add(orderId);
            })
            storeC.forEach(item => {
              if (val.orderId === item.orderId && item.orderTime > val.orderTime) {
                    let orderDetails = {
                          "orderId": item.orderId,
                          "orderTime": item.orderTime
                    }
                    recentOrders.push(orderDetails);
                    uniqOrderIdSet.add(orderId);
            })
          })
      }
```

**This lead Memory call stack size exceeded**

Then I try to put above sync operation inside Async `setTimeout` function to avoid call stack from exceeding its limit like:

```
      let recentOrders = [],
        uniqOrderIdSet = new Set();

      commonOrderList.forEach(val => {

        getOrdersFromStoreA(val);
        getOrdersFromStoreB(val);
        getOrdersFromStoreC(val);

      })

      function getOrdersFromStoreA(val) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          storeA.forEach(item => {
            if (val.orderId === item.orderId && item.orderTime > val.orderTime) {
              let orderDetails = {
                "orderId": item.orderId,
                "orderTime": item.orderTime
              }
              recentOrders.push(orderDetails);
              uniqOrderIdSet.add(orderId);
          })

        }, 6000);
      }

      function getOrdersFromStoreB(val) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          storeB.forEach(item => {
            if (val.orderId === item.orderId && item.orderTime > val.orderTime) {
               let orderDetails = {
                "orderId": item.orderId,
                "orderTime": item.orderTime
              }
              recentOrders.push(orderDetails);
              uniqOrderIdSet.add(orderId);
          })

        }, 3000);
      }

      function getOrdersFromStoreC(val) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          storeC.forEach(item => {
            if (val.orderId === item.orderId && item.orderTime > val.orderTime) {
               let orderDetails = {
                "orderId": item.orderId,
                "orderTime": item.orderTime
              }
              recentOrders.push(orderDetails);
              uniqOrderIdSet.add(orderId);
          })

        }, 8000);
      }
```

But **call Stack exceeded again.** and **it also time consuming process**

I also tried creating `MAP` of **orderId** and **orderTime** but there could be items having same orderId and different orderTime so I need to consider that case also.

So is there any way I can perform this calculation in **less amount of time** and without exceeding memory stack size

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Here is Error stack I am getting:

```
{"name":"retail","hostname":"user-lenovo- 80","pid":26525,"level":20,"msg":"Error occurred in getRecentOrders() ===>     [
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]","time":"2016-10-28T10:48:59.668Z","v":0}
      RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
          at process.nextTick (node.js:478:22)
          at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:343:15)
          at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:89:5)
          at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:690:5)
          at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:700:8)
          at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:300:12)
          at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:286:5)
          at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:214:11)
          at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:626:40)
          at Console.log (console.js:39:16)
```

Comment: That's weird, you shouldn't get a stack overflow from simple array iteration. Are you sure there is no recursion involved? Did you get a stack trace from the exception?

Comment: If there is no special ordering for those arrays, you're basically out of luck for a more efficient solution. You can certainly make your current code faster somehow (e.g. by using loops instead of `forEach` callback calls), but to make a real difference you need to change your stores.

Comment: Why in the world are you holding ~350,000 objects (at least) in memory and trying to do the search in memory??  Why wouldn't you use a database, which is in fact designed for efficient paging and querying?  This query would be fairly trivial in MongoDB, for example, if you want to stay in JS as a language.

Comment: There should not be a stack execeeded. Can you tell us what is going on in here: `//store all those items in recentOrders Array`?

Comment: Do you by any chance used the spread operator somewhere in your code to pass arguments to a function? That might easily have you hit the stack limits.

Comment: There's no code shown here that would cause a stack overflow.  You must not be disclosing something that is relevant to that problem.

Comment: @Bergi Yes there is no recursion involved

Comment: @Paul   - Yes seems doable, I can dynamically store data of three stores in different collections and then query database right?

Comment: @jfriend00  -- I have  made required changes to provide more details and also added error stack you can check now :)

Comment: The stack trace looks like writing data to socket stream. I don't see any of your disclosed code that does that so again I don't think you are disclosing the code that is actually causing the problem.

Comment: @jfriend00   - I have shared everything, there is no point in not disclosing anything because I am getting error while data is being processed in `forEach`. I have just one console log above this error which you can see now

Comment: Can you point to which code is causing that error trace?  The trace refers to `getRecentOrders()`. I don't see the code for that.  My guess is that you're making a wrong assumption about what part of your code is causing this error and thus not disclosing the right code to us.

Comment: @jfriend00  -- Inside that function I have `commonOrderList.forEach`, you can check now, if you are not sure you can try same scenario for 4 arrays of length close to 100k you will get same error I hope :)

Comment: I don't see any stream writing code so I don't know how to explain the stack trace.  Nothing further I can do.

Comment: @shailesh Shekhawat yes, I'd store them in separate collections and then query them. Not sure what you mean by "dynamically ", so maybe if you explain what your goal is?

Comment: @Paul What should be structure to store it in mongodb as I have orderId and corresponding orderTime and comparison is required for same OrderId's and get latest orders

Comment: Depends on a lot of things.  A case could be made for having them all in one collection, if they're all orders, and then having a relationship to the store hat generated them.  If you're trying to split for data sharing, look into mongodbs clustering freatures.  If you really wanted you could also have them as embedded arrays for the store documents, though based on this one use case I wouldn't go that way.